# executing 'grub-install/dev/sda1' failed

Tags: 11.10, installation, grub2

Trying to install Ubuntu 11.10 on a partition of a hard disk, but keep getting this error:

> executing `grub-install/dev/sda1` failed

Can't delete all partitions as there is important data on the other partitions.

Comment: is this partition is a primary one ?

Comment: Is that the exact command you are using?

Comment: `grub-install/dev/sda1` is actually wrong, you need to add a space: `grub-install /dev/sda1`. Also you probably wanted to install it to sda, and not sda1, as the MBR sector, where grub gets installed is only one per drive.

Comment: You may be experiencing this bug that affects many users:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub-installer/+bug/976027

Comment: related post: http://askubuntu.com/q/128937/62483

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason why you want to install the MBR on `/dev/sda1`?
You should try with `grub-install /dev/sda`